# Sentiment Analysis using azure error 'Resource not found'

Tags: python, azure, sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services

I have created a python program that accepts a String as an input and performs sentiment analysis on it.

I have created Environmental variable as stated in DOCUMENTATION and also restart the cmd as well as Visual Studio but still, I get the following error:

> Encountered exception. Operation returned an invalid status code 'Resource Not Found'

The python program is as follows:

```
import os
from azure.cognitiveservices.language.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

#TEXT_ANALYTICS_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = 'b2c4f0ee35c941078d9e6971c15c3472'
#TEXT_ANALYTICS_ENDPOINT = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics'

key_var_name = 'TEXT_ANALYTICS_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'
if not key_var_name in os.environ:
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(key_var_name))
subscription_key = os.environ[key_var_name]

endpoint_var_name = 'TEXT_ANALYTICS_ENDPOINT'
if not endpoint_var_name in os.environ:
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(endpoint_var_name))
endpoint = os.environ[endpoint_var_name]

def authenticateClient():
    credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key)
    text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(
        endpoint=endpoint, credentials=credentials)
    return text_analytics_client

sentence = input("Enter the string:")

def sentiment():

    client = authenticateClient()

    try:
        documents = [
            {"id": "1", "language": "en", "text": sentence}
        ]

        response = client.sentiment(documents=documents)
        for document in response.documents:
            print("Entered Text: ", document.text, ", Sentiment Score: ",
                  "{:.2f}".format(document.score))

    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))
sentiment()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended sharing your subscription key here , pls revoke this subscription key asap .For your issue, try this :

```
import os
from azure.cognitiveservices.language.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

subscription_key = 'b2c4f0ee35c941078d9e6971c15c3472'
endpoint = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/'

def authenticateClient():
    credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key)
    text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(
        endpoint=endpoint, credentials=credentials)
    return text_analytics_client

sentence = input("Enter the string:")

def sentiment():

    client = authenticateClient()

    try:
        documents = [
            {"id": "1", "language": "en", "text": sentence}
        ]



        response = client.sentiment(documents=documents)
        for document in response.documents:
            print("Entered Text: ",sentence ,", Sentiment Score: ",
                  "{:.2f}".format(document.score))


    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))

sentiment()
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: The api was only for demo purpose, it's available for free on azure and valid for 7 days only. Thankyou for solutions. I like it Bro