# Databricks Cognitive Services: name 'TextSentiment' is not defined

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to implement Cognitive Services using the following guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/big-data/getting-started

I have implemented the sample code:

```
from mmlspark.cognitive import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Add your subscription key from the Language service (or a general Cognitive Service key)
service_key = "ADD-SUBSCRIPTION-KEY-HERE"

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("I am so happy today, its sunny!", "en-US"),
  ("I am frustrated by this rush hour traffic", "en-US"),
  ("The cognitive services on spark aint bad", "en-US"),
], ["text", "language"])

sentiment = (TextSentiment()
    .setTextCol("text")
    .setLocation("eastus")
    .setSubscriptionKey(service_key)
    .setOutputCol("sentiment")
    .setErrorCol("error")
    .setLanguageCol("language"))

results = sentiment.transform(df)

# Show the results in a table
display(results.select("text", col("sentiment")[0].getItem("score").alias("sentiment")))
```

I have installed the library Azure:mmlspark:0.17

But I keep on getting the error:

```
name 'TextSentiment' is not defined
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which Spark and Databricks runtime versions are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that currently, there is only one cluster type that can make this tutorial work which is **Databricks Runtime Version: 6.4 Extended Support (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)** as the library supports only Runtime Version 7.0 or below. Also, It seems that you need to install the latest version of the library onto the cluster as follows:

**Coordinate:**
com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3
**Repository:**
https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven

See the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks all for reaching out. I'm using runtime 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12). I will follow PhuriChal's suggestion and use Runtime 6.4

Comment: In the meantime, I'm also trying to get the execute the sentiment analysis on databricks here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189603/sentiment-analysis-using-azure-error-resource-not-found..
Has anyone managed to get it to execute successfully on Databricks

Comment: Hi all, having changed the runtime version to 6.4, I'm not getting the error ```TextSentiment' object has no attribute 'setLocation``` Any thoughts

Comment: I think you might have to check the library version if it is the same as tutorial or not.  Try to reinstall with **com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3**

Comment: The library version I have installed is com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:0.18.1

Comment: The following library versions failed:com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc1 and rc3

Comment: Fail to install? What error did you get?

Comment: ```Library resolution failed. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: unresolved dependency: com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3: not found```

Comment: Any more thoughts on why I'm getting ```TextSentiment' object has no attribute 'setLocation```

Comment: It is because of the wrong version for sure.  But, what I don't know is why you cannot install the latest version as mentioned on the tutorial page (I can install it without any error)

Comment: Hi PhuriChal, thanks for sticking with me on this issue. 
I'm no longer getting that particular error but I'm now getting the following error ```org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field sentiment in score, error-message;``` after I issue the following ```display(sentiment.transform(df).select("text", col("sentiment")[0].getItem("sentiment").alias("sentiment")))``` Any thoughts on this error?

Comment: I tried to install com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3 again, and it failed again

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you create a new Question so that someone else can help us resolve this.